# Git checkout remote branch deleted locally

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-remote

In one of my systems while working on a project, I made changes and pushed it. Now I have a new system with all the same ssh/user details, I cloned that project and wanted to continue my unfinished change by checking out my branch. Here I did one mistake: I made checkout with -b option i.e.

```
git checkout -b mybranch
//instead of 
git checkout mybranch
```

So a blank branch was presented to me instead of cloned remote branch.

So I deleted locally created branch using:

```
git branch -d mybranch
```

I tried below things(by googling) without any success:

```
git checkout --track origin/mybranch
git pull origin origin/mybranch
```

How can I pull and checkout to mybranch?

Comment: Once deleted, you should just be able to `git checkout mybranch` as you said yourself

Comment: You can delete and clone again the project as a workaround method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Asked a colleague to switch to myBranch.
2. Replace contents of my project/.git/config file to his contents for the same file.
3. Checkout myBranch. Works!

This trick worked for me when just commands didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no work laying around there, make the branch look like it was started from the remote branch.

```
# dangerous, that's why i said _if_ there's no work laying around
git reset --hard origin/mybranch # place the local branch where the remote branch is (local branch and worktree content)
git branch --set-upstream origin/mybranch
```

That should be good enough.

But given that you deleted the local branch already

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Should be good enough for git to create the local branch from the remote

Answer (score 0):

Once deleted locally, you cannot recover it but you can recreate it with an other name with the following command :

```
git checkout -b name_of_the_branch origin/name_of_the_branch_on_github
```

`git checkout -b name_of_the_branch` allows you to create a branch starting from the one where you are, if you add an argument, the new branch will start from this argument `origin/name_of_the_branch_on_github` in this example.